# How to show a String Array in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm building an educational app, where I have come categories and then show the stories inside each category.

The use I'm experiencing is how to show a String Array. I can show Strings without any issue. Hope you can help.

Here is the detailed view code that is working and showing the "lesson" (story in this case):

```
struct StoryDetailView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var model: ContentModel
    
    var body: some View {
        
        let story = model.currrentStory
        
        VStack {
            Image(story?.featuredImage ?? "effort")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
            Text(story?.title ?? "error")
            Text(story?.description ?? "error description")
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

I tried this code to show the "explanation", in my case is called "text".

```
ForEach(0..<(story?.text.count ?? ""), id: \.self) { index in
                
                Text(story?.text[index] ?? "notext")
                    .padding(.bottom, 5)
            }
```

I get this error in the "ForEach" line: Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Int'

If I force-unwrap instead of using '??', the app crashes.

Comment: Hi @jnpdx, yes story.text is a [String]. When it's a simple String, it's showing without issue.

Comment: I'm surprised the compiler lets you get away with `story?.text.count ?? ""` -- at the least, it should be `story?.text.count ?? 0` where `0` is the default value, but regardless, see my answer about not relying on indices like this.

Comment: @jnpdx, thank you very much, solved

Comment: Great -- you can accept the answer by clicking the green checkmark

Comment: @jnpdx, done, thank you! Still learning how to use this ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using indices, you should iterate over the array itself in the `ForEach`:

```
ForEach(story?.text ?? []), id: \.self) { item in
  Text(item).padding(.bottom, 5)
}
```

Beware, though that using `.self` on a `ForEach` `id` will fail or produce unexpected results if the array elements aren't truly unique. Consider creating a data model with truly unique `Identifiable` elements.